# Point spring bootstrap project to websitename.com/

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dns, debian, port

I have a fully functioning bootstrap project. Whenever I want to access it locally I go to `localhost:8080`
Now I would like to run it on my server under domain name `websitename.com` and I want to be able to access first page of my bootstrap project without having to type `websitename.com:8080` and instead just type `websitename.com/`

Is there any way to configure the server to do so? Or is this bootstrap configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your port from 8080 to 80. This is the default http port recognized by browsers.

To achieve that you have to add line

`server.port = 80`

to your `application.properties` config file (find details [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-the-http-port))

Note: Depending on operation system usage of 80 port might be restricted to only root user. You'll probably have to run the app with `sudo` or set up http proxy.